# Example for AWS_CORE_API ClientConfiguration using endpointOverride attribute

Tags: c++, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to point dynamodb endpoint to local dummy one for which I want to overwrite endpoint. Existing code is using C++ AWS SDK. While getting [DynamoDBClient](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_dynamo_d_b_1_1_dynamo_d_b_client.html), [config](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/struct_aws_1_1_client_1_1_client_configuration.html#a83b1e084eb22cebcc86e2a8f57b1954b) is passed which can have [endpointOverride](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/struct_aws_1_1_client_1_1_client_configuration.html#a83b1e084eb22cebcc86e2a8f57b1954b) parameter.

I did not find any example with endpointOverride parameter. Can someone please point me to such example?

DynamoDBClient is created as below.

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
Aws::DynamoDB::DynamoDBClient(creds, config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
config.endpointOverride = "localhost:<dynamodb-port>";
config.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTP;
Aws::DynamoDB::DynamoDBClient(creds, config);
```

Comment: Do I need to provide port on which dynamodb service is listening? e.g. config.endpointOverride = "localhost:5959";